# How to write a sql query which matches the listed strings with before and after spaces

Tags: java, sql, sql-like

like want to search `"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"`

Possible matches are all strings that have the exact words and in sequences.

**positive matches are**

```
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text

   123 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 123

   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy edited text

   Lorem text Ipsum text2 is text3 simply text4 dummy text5 text

   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text anytexthere
```

**invalid matches can be**

```
   LoremX XIpsum isX Xsimply dummy text // Not the exact words from input string

   simply dummy text  Lorem Ipsum is // Not in sequence.
 
   Lorem XIpsum is simply dummy text // one word in sequence does not matched

   etc........
```

If not you find it in SQL, would be great if you can think of something in Java/programming also.

Comment: What did you try? Do you know about SQL operators such as `LIKE`? Note that just posting a bunch of requirements is more likely to earn down votes or get your question closed than make people actually willing to help. The more effort _you_ put into a question the more will people be willing to help. You also might want to re-read [ask].

Comment: @Thomas

I tried this   

' NOT FOR OSAMA the BIN LADEN 1 '  LIKE   '% NOT% FOR% OSAMA% BIN% LADEN% 1 %' 
AND  
  ' NOT FOR OSAMA the BIN LADEN 1 '       LIKE      '% NOT %FOR %OSAMA %BIN %LADEN %1 %';


SO far

But  This also matched to 

" NOT FOR MOSAMA OSAMAN the BIN LADEN 1 " which is incorrect

Comment: Did you try `'some totally random string' LIKE '%totally random%'`? You might also want to read up on how `LIKE` actually works and what `%` is meant to do (match any string - so don't put it where you don't want that match).

Comment: @Thomas 

--  'some totally random string' LIKE '%totally random%'

In this case %totally random% may match to "1totally random1" , which is also wrong.

Comment: Well, in that case you could try regular expressions which might also be supported by your database - and if not, read the code into Java (prefilter using `LIKE`) and apply the regex there.